# Difference between a spectroradiometer and multispectral sensor

Tags: remote-sensing, landsat, modis, landsat-8, multi-band

Let's take as an example of a `spectroradiometer` `MODIS`, and as an example of a `multispectral` sensor the `Landsat8 (OLI)`.
What is the difference between these two sensors?

Should we compare a `spectroradiometer` instead with a `hyperspectral` sensor since in the case of `MODIS` the number of bands is more important (36 bands).

Comment: converts invisible (to humans) light to visible Multispectral vs Hyperspectral Imagery Explained see http://gisgeography.com/multispectral-vs-hyperspectral-imagery-explained/

Comment: @Mapperz thanks but I need to compare a spectroradiometer to a multispectral (or hyperspectral) sensor... I've already read that article btw.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [NASA](https://earthdata.nasa.gov/user-resources/remote-sensors), a spectral radiometer *is* a multispectral sensor.

> Spectroradiometer—A radiometer that measures the intensity of radiation in multiple wavelength bands (i.e., multispectral). Many times the bands are of high-spectral resolution, designed for remotely sensing specific geophysical parameters

Perhaps you're thinking of a spectrometer, which is slightly different, but similar

> Spectrometer—A device that is designed to detect, measure, and analyze the spectral content of incident electromagnetic radiation. Conventional imaging spectrometers use gratings or prisms to disperse the radiation for spectral discrimination.

For the sake of being thorough,

> Radiometer—An instrument that quantitatively measures the intensity of electromagnetic radiation in some bands within the spectrum. Usually, a radiometer is further identified by the portion of the spectrum it covers; for example, visible, infrared, or microwave.

And

> Hyperspectral radiometer—An advanced multispectral sensor that detects hundreds of very narrow spectral bands throughout the visible, near-infrared, and mid-infrared portions of the electromagnetic spectrum. This sensor’s very high spectral resolution facilitates fine discrimination between different targets based on their spectral response in each of the narrow bands.

[MODIS](http://modis.gsfc.nasa.gov/about/specifications.php) has an imaging spectroradiometer that measures 36 bands.  Bands 1-19 are relatively wide, and imagery from these bands is considered multispectral.  Bands 20-36 are much more fine, covering a nearly continuous spectral range, resulting in hyperspectral imagery.

[image]

The [Operational Land Imager (OLI)](http://landsat.usgs.gov/ldcm_vs_previous.php) on [Landsat 8](http://landsat.usgs.gov/landsat8.php) is also a multispectral sensor.

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks for the comprehensive list of definitions. No I meant a `spectroradiometer` (The `S` in `MODIS`). According to what you said, I understand that `MODIS` could be classified as a `hyperspectral` radiometer too, although since its bands are used to extract specific geophysical parameters (the water mask is an example) they call it a `spectroradiometer` maybe...

Comment: @h4k1m You might take a look at http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/101384/ where the definition of 'hyperspectral' is discussed. While MODIS does have quite a few bands, I'm not sure I'd classify it as hyperspectral. Blake - your MODIS statement is a little confusing because you mention "along bands" and "from 250m to 1km" which is mixing *spatial* resolution with *spectral* resolution.  You then go on to talk about OLI in terms of its *spectral* resolution. Spectral is given in nm/wavelength. But I think your answer is basically sound  as summed in your first sentence.

Comment: That's right, Chris.  I've edited my answer to clarify that a little better.  Feel free to add anything you think might help.

Comment: @ChrisW Sorry I meant `multispectral`. My question was whether `MODIS` which is a `spectroradimeter` could be considered a `multispectral radiometer`. According to what @BlakeG said indeed `MODIS` could be categorized as a `multispectral radiometer`. Thanks

Comment: @ChrisW In the link you gave, should we replace `radiometer` with `multispectral sensor` and `spectrometer` with `hyperspectral sensor`?.

Comment: @h4k1m I don't believe so. A radiometer could be measuring a single, narrow band, in which case it wouldn't be multispectral. And you could have a spectrometer paired with optics/filters that only look at a few broad bands, so it wouldn't be hyperspectral (by either narrowness or number of bands). I think it's more an issue of umbrella terms, specific instruments, and interchangeable prefixes. But don't let me fool you - I'm not an expert in this area and most of my knowledge comes from a single Remote Sensing course and it's book/materials, not everyday or even frequent experience.